How to avoid printing bash commands getting displayed in Github action workflow job summary
Below are the commands running on my reusable workflow(which is called by other repository's workflow).But when I could see those commands getting populated in the job summary of calling repository.
enter image description here
I have tried /dev/null but no luck.
Could you please help on this?
Error Response when trying to checkout reusable repository:
enter image description here

Why do you want to? If a value should be secret make it a secret, but hiding what the workflow's doing just makes it harder to solve any problems with it.

Thanks for your reply, just wanted to restrict the logics what exactly happening inside this workflow.

I have added the Error Response, here highlighted in RED is my resuable repo and green is actual calling repo

Put everything you want to execute in a script file (ex: auth.sh) and execute it. The workflow log will show the script call, but not the actual commands.

Thanks for your reply. I have tired that unfortunately its a reusable workflow and I kept that .sh file inside this repository, while execution its failing with file not found error because calling repositoryis getting checkedout. I have also tried to checkout the resuable Workflow's repository with (actions/checkout@v2) and that too failed with below error

Yes, first you need to clone the repository with actions/checkout and then you can execute the reusable workflow and the script. What is the error?

I have added the Error Response; here highlighted in RED is my reusable repo and green is actual calling repo

It seems to be a permission issue, but it can't be other problems too, see here: https://github.com/actions/checkout/issues/347, and here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67949370/github-action-default-branch-not-found-on-privat-repository, and here:
